# Expected value of distance of random vector from its mean

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm looking for information about the following situation:
I have a random vector $X$ which gives values in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Denote its expected value by $\mu$. If $\{X_i\}$ all share the same distribution as $X$, I need to be able to calculate (or bound from below) the value $\mathbb{E}\left\| \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \mu \right\|$.
I tried searching for information about this but I couldn't find anything. I assume that I didn't know what to search for.

Notice that this is the norm and not the squared norm. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without knowledge of the particular distribution of the $X_i$, you can invoke the law of large numbers and assume a Gaussian $\mathcal N(\mu,\frac{\Sigma}{\sqrt n})$ for the arithmetic mean, where $\Sigma$ denotes the variance-covariance matrix.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Do you known the law of large numbers ?

Comment: So you want a lower bound on this expected norm? What are your assumptions on the distribution of $X$?

Comment: Are the $X_i$ independent?

Comment: The distribution of $X_i$ is unknown, but I think that using their expected value/variance should help. They are indeed independent.